# How to properly delete fields, programmatically?

Tags: entities, 8

I have two content types on my site and I just deleted all the nodes using `$node->delete()`.

For one of the content types, I noticed that the node body fields did not get deleted, nor did one of the custom fields I made for the content type. All the fields for my other content type were deleted .

So I researched and found the [`field_purge_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!field.purge.inc/function/field_purge_field/8) function. I am not sure how to actually use the function, which is defined as `function field_purge_field(FieldConfigInterface $field)`.
Can someone describe how I would actually load a field and then delete it in this manner (or in a better manner)?

Could I just truncate the tables?

Answer (score 5):

`field_purge_field()` is described as follows:

> This function assumes all data for the field has already been purged and should only be called by [`field_purge_batch()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.purge.inc/function/field_purge_batch/8).

On Drupal, fields are effectively removed during cron tasks; in fact, `field_purge_batch()` is called from [`field_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_cron/8), the implementation of `hook_cron()` done from the Field module. There is no need for you to call neither `field_purge_field()` nor `field_purge_batch()`.

If you want to write code to purge fields for a node bundle, that code would be similar to the following one. (See the notes after the code, thought.)

```
  $properties = array(
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'Your bundle (a.k.a. content type)',
    'include_deleted' => TRUE,
  );

  $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();

  $fields = $entity_manager->getStorage('field_config')->loadByProperties($properties);

  $info = $entity_manager->getDefinitions();
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $entity_type = $field->getTargetEntityTypeId();

    // Proceed only if the module implementing the entity has not been uninstalled already.
    if (isset($info[$entity_type])) {
      $entity_manager->getStorage($entity_type)->purgeFieldData($field, 100);
      field_purge_field($field);
    }
  }
```

#### Notes

- Purging the fields is thought to be ran during cron tasks; that is why `Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage()->purgeFieldData()` requires the batch size as argument. I used a value of 100, which would possibly allow the code to purge all the fields for that content type, but it could also cause a PHP timeout error. It would be better to run the code from PHP CLI, in order to avoid any execution time out.
- You should not need to use this code; in most of the cases, you should execute the cron tasks (which is when Drupal purges the fields of a deleted bundle), or use Drush to purge the fields, either running `hook_cron()` with it, or executing a specific Drush command (if it exists).

As for truncating the tables, that is the wrong way to proceed. It would not allow Drupal and third-party modules to delete the data they have for the fields; even if you know which tables Drupal uses, you could forget a table used by third-party modules.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Where does $fields come from? Is it the output of the loadByProperties() function?

Comment: Yes, it is. I forgot a part while replacing a function used by Drupal code.

Comment: what about locked fields, I need to delete just one field that is locked, I tried that solution but i didn't catch the field to delete

Comment: @MohammedGomma It is probable that locked fields cannot be deleted, so you cannot even purge them.

Answer (score 5):

The updated version for **Drupal 8.3.x** using non deprecated functions:

```
/**
 * Removes field_MY_FIELD_NAME.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_8001() {
  /* @var $entityFieldManager Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager */
  $entityFieldManager = Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');

  $fields = $entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions('ENTITY_TYPE', 'BUNDLE');

  if (isset($fields['field_MY_FIELD_NAME'])) {
    $fields['field_MY_FIELD_NAME']->delete();
  }
}
```

Replace the following:

1. `ENTITY_TYPE` by the entity type, e.g.: `'taxonomy_term'`, `'node'`...
2. `BUNDLE` by the bundle, e.g.: `'article'`, `'tags'`...
3. `field_MY_FIELD_NAME` by the field machine name, e.g.: `'field_description'`...

Comment: Thank you, this actually deleted the field instances for me. I don't know why purge_field didn't work, maybe it's because I'm using a custom entity?

Comment: The `delete()` method is undefined in Drupal 8.6

Comment: The `delete()` function is still here, in `EntityInterface`. You have to type-hint `$fields` to something like `FieldConfigInterface[]` to help your IDE to find the `delete()` function. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Adelete/8.7.x

Comment: Out of the box Drupal should already delete a field and purge all of its data when doing so via a config import (e.g. drush cim). This was implemented in 2014  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2198429.

So the above code should only be needed if that approach failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The following will delete content and config of a field in all places used on the same entity type. NOTE: in D7 fields could be used across entity types (i.e. same field used on different bundles of same entity type) but in D8, this is not allowed:

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
FieldStorageConfig::loadByName(ENTITY_TYPE_NAME, FIELD_NAME)->delete();
```

As with the other methods above, this will result in field remnants being left behind in the key_value and cachetags tables. CRON runs will remove remnants from the key_value table but I have not yet found a way to remove remnants from the cachetags table (short of simply using direct db calls).

[EDIT]
I stated that field remnants from key_value table would be removed during CRON; but in fact this only occurs if there had been data in that field. Not sure why this is different but likely a core bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code for drupal 8 that worked very good for me here 
https://gist.github.com/jacerider/78b926acbb201666a0fc3a1f8102cb44

**This empty the field, them remove field from bundle**

I just added in a hook_update_N() 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.2.x

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

$bundles = ['user'];

$fields['user_picture'] = [
  'entity_type' => 'user',
];

foreach ($bundles as $bundle) {
  foreach ($fields as $field_name => $config) {
    $field = FieldConfig::loadByName($config['entity_type'], $bundle, $field_name);
    if (!empty($field)) {
      $field->delete();
    }
  }
}

foreach ($fields as $field_name => $config) {
  $field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($config['entity_type'], $field_name);
  if (!empty($field_storage)) {
    $field_storage->delete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 8 we had a lot of issues after uninstalling the domain module.

We solved this with an install file

```
@file my_module.install

/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function my_module_update_8800(&$sandbox) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\DeletedFieldsRepositoryInterface $deleted_fields_repository */
  $deleted_fields_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_field.deleted_fields_repository');
  $fields = $deleted_fields_repository->getFieldDefinitions();
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    field_purge_field($field);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.