# Delete locked fields, programmatically

Tags: entities, 8

I have upgraded a website to drupal 8 that I found a field created and I need to delete that field as it became useless.

The field is locked, and this prevents me delete it from the interface.
I tried to delete it using [`field_purge_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.purge.inc/function/field_purge_field/8.2.x), but it didn't work either.

The answer for [How to properly delete fields, programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177156/how-to-properly-delete-fields-programmatically) didn't work for me.

**Edit**:
I tried that piece of code but didn't do any thing

```
$field = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load($entity_type.$bundle_name.$field_machine_name);
field_purge_field($field);
```

How do I delete fields that result locked? How do I unlock them before deleting them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Purging is the second step, after the field was deleted. field.module should do that automatically for you.

A field config is an entity, you delete it like any other entity:

```
$field->delete();
```

Comment: ^^ yes,  let's preserve tedious adherence to the letter of the rules instead of getting it right,  especially when the tediousness gets it wrong.
The edit which was proposed is what is needed to accomplish *full* deletion:

$field = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load($entity_type.$bundle_name.$field_machine_name);
$field->delete();
field_purge_field($field);

Answer (score 1):

Here is this answer, more plainly, tested and working:

```
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('my_entity_type.my_bundle.my_field_name');
```

But remember, the best way to do this, if you can, is simply to delete the field through the UI and then export your configuration using `drush cex`